# VS2015 Test Explorer doesn't run or show test results

Tags: visual-studio, nunit

The Test Explorer shows all the tests in my project correctly, so my problem doesn't match the search-results I keep finding about tests not showing up, but when I "Run All", or select and run a single test, nothing is run. If I debug the tests, they do step into each test.

[image: List of tests]

The output in the Test window says:

```
------ Run test started ------
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is started
Loading tests from C:\Project\bin\Debug\Project.Tests.dll
Run started: C:\Project\bin\Debug\Project.Tests.dll
NUnit VS Adapter 2.0.0.0 executing tests is finished
========== Run test finished: 0 run (0:00:03.2384917) ==========
```

I have the following NuGet packages installed in this project:

- NUnit
- NUnit.Runners
- NunitTestAdapter
- NUnit.Console

Comment: Same issue here with xunit and VS2015 - I have one solution where it works, and one solution with this issue, and no idea why...@Raffaeu & @Cylindric, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installed the packages correctly. If you are using NUnit you have to install the [NUnit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/) package.

Comment: Well it's weird. It sometimes runs some of them. So if I hit "Run All", maybe the first test will get a green tick. Or maybe the half of them flick to "running", then back to the grey-with-blue-exclamation "not run" status. I have "NUnit", "NUnit.Runners", "NunitTestAdapter" and "NUnit.Console" packages installed with NuGet now, but no difference.

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue since today and I use MsTest. I also deleted the testresults folder, recompile and nothing change. Tests are discovered but non of them is executed. Going mad

Comment: For me, I missed installing Xunit Runner Nuget for the test project